# Hook in CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol

Tags: delegates, hook, cllocationmanager, jailbreak

I have a problem from 3 days :( I want to hook in CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I tried everything but without success. I know how to hook into class or framework but I can't find a solution to hook a Delegate.
Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hooking requires you to provide objective-C class you would like to hook. This is what `Class` type is for. One way to get obj-c class is by name via `objc_getClass` function. But in your case as I understand it correctly you don't have the name. You want to hook every class that conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol and implements specific method. Here is what you can do.

You can obtain every registered obj-C class and search for those which conform to`CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol like this:

```
static IMP original_didUpdateLocations;
void replaced_didUpdateLocations(id self, SEL _cmd, CLLocationManager* manager, NSArray* locations)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ did update locations to %@", manager, locations);

    original_didUpdateLocations(self, _cmd, manager, locations);
}
```

...

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

Class* list = (Class*)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
objc_getClassList(list, numClasses);    

for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++)
{
    if (class_conformsToProtocol(list[i], @protocol(CLLocationManagerDelegate)) && 
        class_getInstanceMethod(list[i], @selector(locationManager:didUpdateLocations:)))
    {
        MSHookMessageEx(list[i], @selector(locationManager:didUpdateLocations:), (IMP)replaced_didUpdateLocations, (IMP*)&original_didUpdateLocations);
    }
}

free(list);
```

1. We need to know how many classes there is. `objc_getClassList(NULL, 0)` returns number of all registered classes.
2. Allocating memory with `malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses)` and filling it with objects of type `Class` using `objc_getClassList(list, numClasses)`.
3. Searching through all these classes for those which conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol and implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method. If we found one we are hooking it with our own implementation.
4. In our own implementation we are printing some debug message and calling original implementation before returning. Of course, you can do whatever you what, this is just an example.
5. Freeing allocated memory using `free(list)`.

Comment: Thanks for replay but I have a problem with this code. Usually I use logos in iOSOpenDev and I hook class in this way:
`%hook ClassName -(void)Action {      //Hooked launch  }  %end`
how can I use your code? Or how can I translate your code in logos? 
Thanks again

Comment: I don't think you can use logos if you don't know exact class name you want to hook. My code requires you to use Mobile Substrate API manually. Code will not be very pretty but it's not that much more difficult to use than logos.

Comment: I've updated my answer with complete example. Should be no problem getting it to compile and run.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very kind! But I'm not able to compile this code, I don't understand in which project I have to put it :(

Comment: I found a document ([link](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.priyaontech.com%2Fdownload%2F12%2F&ei=Fqe4UsDUNqn1yAPSu4HYCw&usg=AFQjCNGilwd4UpBSNUMKkjRCy18S0dBc6A&sig2=1WjruioTXw82uzRQfYqLuA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.Yms)
on page 30...) with example to translate code for logos but is very hard for me... Any help is appreciated!  Please help me!

Comment: Just use that code in your tweak.xm as the common `c/c++` code.