# Private API's for location spoofing in ios 7

Tags: ios, location, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, spoofing

Can anyone help me in searching for API's for Location spoofing,for all apps running on iPhone
like application available on cydia (fake location etc.)

Comment: What have you tried? You question has very obvious solution that doesn't require knowledge of any private APIs. You just need to create a very simple cydia substrate tweak. Maybe you have a more specific problem.

Comment: for sure i want to spoof any location for any application running and asking for location from CLLocation manager, for example if we want to spoof UDID of device in jail broken device () we can use fakeUDID application ,and from my application code we can change plist of UDIDfaker APPlication (available on Cydia) for particular apps bundle identifier, i don't know how that application work but it makes my work done.
so just like this FackLocation must contain some location info that can be changed for my code...\

Comment: You want to know how FakeLocation does it or you want to write your own implementation? If latter, as I said, simple cydia substrate tweak with CoreLocation framework as a filter and you're good to go.

Comment: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20735457/119114) should do what you need.

Comment: Or you could hook a couple of `CLLocationManager` methods and call delegate methods yourself. Either way should work I think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this for sure but the app on cydia *probably* uses the [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html) framework, which is a public framework, not private.

If you're dying to sift through a private framework, take a look into the [GeoServices](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework) framework, I'm not sure if it has what you're looking for though.

Comment: I know you probably don't have enough reputation points to comment yet (silly rule, I know), but in general, if you only have a *guess* for how to get started, it's better to post that as a **comment** below the question, rather than a full-blown answer here.

Comment: Ah, yes. My appologizes.